# mysql_insert_id() returning 0 even though the last insert was a success

Tags: php, mysql

```
$tSQL = "insert into events(title,start,end,allday,url,customerid) VALUES(\"" . $_POST['title'] . "\", FROM_UNIXTIME($epochstart), FROM_UNIXTIME($epochend), \"$allday\", \"$url\", \"$customerid\")";
$mysqli->multi_query($tSQL);
$lasterror = $mysqli->error;



$tSQL = "update events set url = \"details.php?\"" . mysql_insert_id() . " where idevents = \"$eventid\"";
$row = $mysqli->multi_query($tSQL);
$lasterror = $mysqli->error;

echo print_r($tSQL);
```

My insert statement for sure does insert the record however mysql_insert_id() keeps returning 0. It should not be this way because there is an auto incremented primary key in that events table and that is running fine as well. Any suggestions on how to get the last inserted ID?

Comment: replace `mysql_insert_id()` with `mysqli_insert_id()`

Comment: So many good answers and none accepted...

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. I accepted the answer by Vulcan. As it was the first and was a very good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is executed via `mysqli`, so the `mysql` function would not hold the inserted ID.  Instead, use [the `mysqli` version](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php):

```
$id = $mysqli->insert_id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I got sidetracked or I would have marked the answer much sooner.

Comment: This may not work if your primary index column is not `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Answer (score 4):

Becasue you are using `mysqli` and not `mysql`,

Simply replace `mysql_insert_id()` with `mysqli_insert_id()` if using *Procedural style*

Or replace it with `$mysqli->insert_id` if using *Object Oriented Style*

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using mysqli extension, change

```
$tSQL = "update events set url = \"details.php?\"" . mysql_insert_id() . " where idevents = \"$eventid\"";
```

to

```
$tSQL = "update events set url = \"details.php?\"" .$mysqli->insert_id. " where idevents = \"$eventid\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your are using `mysqli` which is an improvement version of `mysql`.

Use `mysqli->insert_id` instead of `mysql->insert_id()`

```
$tSQL = "insert into events(title,start,end,allday,url,customerid) VALUES(\"" . $_POST['title'] . "\", FROM_UNIXTIME($epochstart), FROM_UNIXTIME($epochend), \"$allday\", \"$url\", \"$customerid\")";
    $mysqli->multi_query($tSQL);
    $lasterror = $mysqli->error;

    $lastInsId=$mysqli->insert_id();

    $tSQL = "update events set url = \"details.php?\"" . $lastInsId . " where idevents = \"$eventid\"";
    $row = $mysqli->multi_query($tSQL);
    $lasterror = $mysqli->error;

    echo print_r($tSQL);
```